# gender input loop keeps repeating even if I enter "m" or "f"

Tags: python

If it's not m or f, repeat prompt until it's either or. I typed m or f, but the loop keeps repeating. Why?

```
gender = input('m/f? ')

while gender != 'm' or gender != 'f': 
    print("Type 'm' or 'f'") 
    gender = input('m/f? ') 
if gender == 'm': 
    gender = 'him' 
elif gender == 'f': 
    gender = 'her' 

print("It read {}".format(gender))
```

Answer (score 3):

Just say `gender` is `m`. Look at this statement:

```
while gender != 'm' or gender != 'f':
```

Is `gender!='m'`? No. `Or`... Is `gender!='f'`? Yes! OK, keep `while`ing!

You don't want `or`, you want `and`

Answer (score 0):

Because of this line :
`while gender != 'm' or gender != 'f':`

Use instead :
`while gender != 'm' and gender != 'f':`

`gender` cannot simultaneously contain 'm' and 'f'

Answer (score 0):

The basic fundamental

True or True : True

**True or False : True**

**False or True : True**

False or False : False

You have to continue asking for input as long as both the conditions are not satisfied.

Or has to be replaced by 'and'.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
gender = raw_input('m/f?')

while True: 
    print("Type 'm' or 'f'") 
    gender = raw_input('m/f? ') 
    if gender=='m' or gender=='f':
        break

if gender == 'm': 
    gender = 'him' 
elif gender == 'f': 
    gender = 'her'
```

print("It read {}".format(gender))

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of answers already, but I think the most Pythonic way, which also eliminates the AND/OR confusion is, and is easily extendable if you want to add, say, `o` for `other`

```
while gender not in 'mf':
```

That is, while `gender` is not present in the list of genders.

Answer (score 0):

In your while, you are checking to see if either the string gender does not equal 'm' OR 'f', which will always be the case because it cannot be both.

Change or to and to fix this.